# Remove last appeared comma in string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a text

> test, text, 123, without last comma

I need it to be

> test, text, 123 without last comma

(no comma after 123). How to achieve this using JavaScript?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
str.replace(/,(?=[^,]*$)/, '')
```

This uses a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to replace a comma followed only by non-commata.

Comment: Short, exact and with explanation! Thank you.

Comment: ♡ Take that, oxford comma - muuuhahahahaha `.replace(/,(?=[^,]*$)/, ' and')`

Answer (score 9):

A non-regex option:

```
var str = "test, text, 123, without last comma";
var index = str.lastIndexOf(",");
str = str.substring(0, index) + str.substring(index + 1);
```

But I like [the regex one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14355832/157247). :-)

Comment: :( didn't know that javasctipt has lastIndexOf.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to replace with regex:

```
str.replace(/([/s/S]*),/, '$1')
```

This relies on the fact that `*` is greedy, and the regex will end up matching the last `,` in the string. `[/s/S]` matches any character, in contrast to `.` that matches any character but new line.